# Convert EF5 indirect many-to-many table to direct

Tags: c#, sql, .net, entity-framework-core

We have a many-to-many table which is handled without a specific entity, I need to add a new column to it so I have to convert it to a class in my .Net application, however I keep running into the issues because the table already exists.

Creating the class object with the new column and trying to add the migration throws the error "Cannot use table '' for entity type ' (Dictionary<string, Object>)' since it is being used for entity type '' and potentially other entity types, but there is no linking relationship."

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no EF experience so I don't know how to recreate this issue and the person who does is long gone.